# VBA help to include an if statement then ignore in my current VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Really need help to rewrite the existing code I have to include an if statement. The VBA code creates and renames my tabs based on the data in column A in the worksheet "paste L3 here".
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4zNa.png)
I need the code to ignore & move on to the next row if the cell in column C of the same row = "Reversed" (may be caps or lower case).

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetsFromTemplate()
Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet, wasVISIBLE As Boolean
Dim shNAMES As Range, Nm As Range
With ThisWorkbook                                               'keep focus in this workbook
    Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("Template")                            'sheet to be copied
    wasVISIBLE = (wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible)              'check if it's hidden or not
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible      'make it visible

    Set wsMASTER = .Sheets("Paste L3 here")                            'sheet with names
                                                                'range to find names to be checked
    Set shNAMES = wsMASTER.Range("A4:A" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlConstants)     'or xlFormulas

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False                              'speed up macro
    For Each Nm In shNAMES                                      'check one name at a time
    If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & CStr(Nm.Text) & "'!A1)") Then  'if sheet does not exist...
        If UCase$(Nm.Offset(0, 2).Value) <> "REVERSED" Then   '... Check if "Reversed" is present 2 columns to the right (C in this case)
            wsTEMP.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)     '...create it from template
            ActiveSheet.Name = CStr(Nm.Text)              '...rename it
        End If
    End If
Next Nm

    wsMASTER.Activate                                           'return to the master sheet
    If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetHidden       'hide the template if necessary
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True                           'update screen one time at the end
End With

MsgBox "All sheets created"
End Sub
```

Comment: I just wonder: *how* you were given this code to rewrite? SO is not a free-coding service.

Comment: What have you tried? You seem to understand the basic idea which is sufficient to have a go.

Comment: Hi both, thanks for the comments. Sadly I am not very proficient in VBA however very much looking to learn. I found this code from another website, happy to spend time researching but sadly struggling to adapt anything I can find. I think I need some kind of if statement but can't manage to fit it in with the existing code.
Thanks

Charlotte

Answer (score 0):

I won't rewrite all this, but I believe you just need to extend your existing if statement, either with an OR condition, or just nest another if:

```
For Each Nm In shNAMES                         'check one name at a time
    If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & CStr(Nm.Text) & "'!A1)") Then  'if sheet does not exist...
        if ucase$(nm.offset(0, 2).value) <> "RESERVED" then   '... Check if "Reserved" is present 2 columns to the right (C in this case)
            wsTEMP.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)     '...create it from template
            ActiveSheet.Name = CStr(Nm.Text)              '...rename it
        end if
    End If
Next Nm
```

If it doesn't work as intended, it should get on you on right direction at least.

UPDATED:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SheetsFromTemplate()

    Dim wsMASTER As Worksheet, wsTEMP As Worksheet, wasVISIBLE As Boolean
    Dim shNAMES As Range, Nm As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
    'keep focus in this workbook
        Set wsTEMP = .Sheets("Template")         'sheet to be copied
        wasVISIBLE = (wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible) 'check if it's hidden or not

        If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetVisible 'make it visible

        Set wsMASTER = .Sheets("Paste L3 here")  'sheet with names'range to find names to be checked
        Set shNAMES = wsMASTER.Range("A4:A" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlConstants) 'or xlFormulas

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False       'speed up macro

        For Each Nm In shNAMES                         'check one name at a time

            If Not Evaluate("ISREF('" & CStr(Nm.Text) & "'!A1)") Then  'if sheet does not exist...

                If UCase$(nm.offset(0, 2).Value) <> "RESERVED" Then   '... Check if "Reserved" is present 2 columns to the right (C in this case)

                    wsTEMP.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)     '...create it from template
                    ActiveSheet.Name = CStr(Nm.Text)              '...rename it

                End If

            End If

        Next Nm

        wsMASTER.Activate
        'return to the master sheet
        If Not wasVISIBLE Then wsTEMP.Visible = xlSheetHidden 'hide the template if necessary

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True        'update screen one time at the end

    End With

    MsgBox "All sheets created"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will give this a try now and let you know if it works.

Comment: Sadly can't seem to get this to work but your input was much appreciated anyway - trying to look online for a solution but very difficult when I am so new to VBA - lots to learn.

Thanks again

Comment: Any chance you can detail the error you've received? Might be able to help if you further detail on the error.
Also, in case it wasn't clear from my response (i mean no ofense!), you will need to replace the section in your code "For Each Nm ..... Next Nm" with the one that I've gave you.
In all honesty, I haven't tested the initial ammendment I've gave you, but now I did, and it definitely works.

Comment: Hi, I have pasted the sub as it is now, I think I have missed an "and" or an "or"? No offense will be taken - I am a total beginner at VBA

Comment: Hi @Charlotte879, I`m not sure you are actually replacing the code as advised above, or just trying to use it on its own... please see my updated answer. Again, will be easier to help you if you detail on the error you are receiving, or post a screenshot of it... also you can try to run the code using F8, and with mouse over the text (or using the VIEW > LOCALS) check if everything is working as intended.

Comment: Thank you. I have pasted my current code by amending my original code above, however I can see if I can attach the file that may be easier I will try that now...
I don't get any errors the code runs fine, however it still inserts a sheet for those called "reserved"

Comment: Hyperlink added to my original description to a picture of the file..not sure if that helps in anyway

Comment: Well.. in your original post you said "Reversed", not **"Reserved"** hence the issue... so just amend the correct word within the code should do :)